# Using rvest to get tables from baseball-reference.com

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to get 2018 'Player Standard Batting' table from baseball-reference.com.  there are multiple tables on  the URL page and when i run the following code. I'm only able to get the first table in the table list. I need the second table which is the player standard batting.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-batting.shtml"
pg <- read_html(url)
tb <- html_table(pg, fill = TRUE)
df_batting <- tb[[1]]
```

Comment: If you view the HTML source, you'll see that the other tables are in a comment. The answer is contained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616357/how-to-scrape-tables-inside-a-comment-tag-in-html-with-r