# RVest html_nodes() function not recognizing web element

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I an attempt to run the following code to scrape the table titled "Advanced", whos id is also dictated as "advanced":

```
url <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/GSW/2016.html")
      webpage <- read_html(url)
      col_names <- webpage %>% 
        html_nodes("table#advanced")
```

However, when I run this code and try to print `col_names`, I receive the following value: `{xml_nodeset (0)}`. How can I properly scrape my desired table?

Comment: The table I am attempting to scrape is titled "Advanced" and its `id` is listed as `advanced`. It is about 1/4 of the way down the page. It is a subset of `div id` `content`

Comment: Table is in comments. You need to extract from there. There are existing answers on SO for this e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616357/how-to-scrape-tables-inside-a-comment-tag-in-html-with-r  (have a look at some of the existing. This was just the first Google SO return.)